# Pass customer billing address to PayPal via chained payment?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained-payments

Is it possible to pass the customer's billing address when using PayPal Adaptive's Chained Payments? Currently users enter their shipping and billing address on my marketplace store, and then have to enter their name, email address, billing address all over again on the PayPal checkout page if they are using PayPal's guest checkout option (pay with debit/credit card). Ideally I'd like to somehow pass this through when they move from my checkout to the PayPal payment screen, which is done via Parallel Payment using Adaptive Payments (Classic API).

Answer (score 0):

Paypal have an option to pass variables to their pages.
Could this be what you are looking for? 
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HI0J0VU

Alternatively, please check here, this is specific for Adaptive and has payer details:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/PaymentDetails_API_Operation/